# AssertionError: Bad context propagation - OpenERP

Tags: odoo, assert, stock

I am getting "AssertionError: Bad context propagation" error in openerp stock/wizard/stock_partial_picking.py file. I get this error on clicking Deliver button on my custom delivery order. Below is the log:

Client Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
  File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1128, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(req, model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1120, in _call_kw
    return getattr(req.session.model(model), method)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/web/session.py", line 42, in proxy
    result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid, self.session._password, self.model, method, args, kw)
  File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
  File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)
```

Server Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 296, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/openerp/addons/stock/wizard/stock_partial_picking.py", line 115, in default_get
    assert active_model in ('stock.picking', 'stock.picking.in', 'stock.picking.out'), 'Bad context propagation'
AssertionError: Bad context propagation
```

Answer (score 0):

There has to be an `active_model` key in the context dictionary with a value of either `'stock.picking'`, `'stock.picking.in'` or `'stock.picking.out'`. Your custom delivery order probably does not pass the correct value or does not pass any value at all but there is no way I can help further here without seeing the code.

I'm not sure this is the correct place for asking such questions anyway. Try joining the irc chan #openobject on freenode, people will be able to help you there.